# changing styles of a class with its own id

Tags: css

I have a lot of form-controls in div classes of my website and i want to change the style of only 1 form-control. How it is possible? i tried to give an id but it did not work.

```
<ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar">
                <li><input type="search" className="form-control" id="this" placeholder="Search" id="search_input" /></li>
                <div className="col-sm-1">
                <li><button type = 'button' onClick={submitSearch}>Search</button></li>
                <li>
                    <div id="search_results">
                    </div>
                </li>
                </div>
 </ul>
```

So i want to change the style of this form-control only! how should write is in my css file? Than you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got 2 IDs on the same input..

`<input type="search" className="form-control" id="this" placeholder="Search" id="search_input" />`

That may be why you are having problems. Remove one of the IDs and then target the other via css.

`<input type="search" className="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="search_input" />`

```
input#search_input { /* css style here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter some selectors you can use pesudo element:

```
.form-control:first-of-type //First in its parent
.form-control:last-of-type  //last in its parent
.form-control:nth-child(2)  //.form-control only where it is second element of its parent
```